# $S \neq R^n$ or $\emptyset \implies \partial S \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, alternative-proof

I want to show that $S \neq \mathbb R^n$ and $S \neq \emptyset \implies \partial S \neq \emptyset$ using the following property : Let $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ a compact set and $T \subset \mathbb R^n$ a closed set, both are not empty et $S \cap T = \emptyset$. Then $\exists a \in S$ and $b \in T$ such that $$inf(\lvert\lvert x-y \rvert \rvert : x \in S, y \in T) = \lvert\lvert a-b \rvert \rvert > 0$$
I hesitate about the way to do this, I don't know what I need to take to be my compact set and closed set and the next steps are also not very clear.

(I already know the easy proof with $\partial S = \emptyset \implies \overline{S}=\mathring{S}=S \implies S = \mathbb R^n$ or $S = \emptyset $, I want to use the given property to show the proposition.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $S \ne \emptyset, \Bbb{R}^n$ be a set such that $\partial S = \emptyset$. Then there exists a closed ball $K$ large enough such that $\overline{S} \cap K$ and $\overline{S^c} \cap K$ are both nonempty. Hence they are two disjoint nonempty compact sets so there exist
$$a \in \overline{S} \cap K, \quad b \in \overline{S^c} \cap K$$
which minimize the distance between $\overline{S} \cap K$ and $\overline{S^c} \cap K$.

Consider the element $\frac{a+b}2$. It is certainly in $K$ since $K$ is convex. We have
$$\left\|a-\frac{a+b}2\right\| = \left\|b-\frac{a+b}2\right\| = \frac12\|a-b\|$$
so

- $\frac{a+b}2$ is closer to $a$ than $b$ is and hence it cannot be in $\overline{S^c} \cap K$,
- $\frac{a+b}2$ is closer to $b$ than $a$ is and hence it cannot be in $\overline{S} \cap K$.

This is a contradiction since clearly
$$K = (\overline{S} \cap K) \cup (\overline{S^c} \cap K).$$

Comment: The closed ball $K$ large enough such that $\overline{S} \cap K$ and $\overline{S^c} \cap K$ are both nonempty can only be $\mathbb R^n$ or can it be something else (for example a "hand-made" closed ball containing some (not all) elements of S and some (not all) elements of $S^C$  ?

Comment: @John Since $S \ne \emptyset, \Bbb{R}^n$, both $S$ and $S^c$ are nonempty. So we can pick some $x \in S$ and $y \in S^c$. Now let $R := \max\{\|x\|, \|y\|\} > 0$ and let $K = \overline{B}(0,R)$. Then $$x \in \overline{S} \cap K, \quad y \in \overline{S^c} \cap K$$
so both are nonempty.